# How to make a categorization rule which matches on recipient address when using a distribution list?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I've created a rule to categorize some emails when received. When the email name exists in TO or CC the rule is working successfully and the category is coloured appropriately.

When my email ID exists within a Distribution List (DL), regardless of being in the TO or CC field, the rule doesn't categorize the mail.

Can anybody tell me how to create the 2 rules, one for when my email exists within a DL (TO field) and the other for when the email exists within the CC field?

Comment: OK, my apologies, missed it being there,

Comment: Is it possible to add the distribution list name into a new rule?